# Android. Обработка нажатия button в статусбаре

Tags: java, android, xml, button, уведомления

Как можно обработать нажатие на button "apps"?

> [image: StatusBar кнопка apps]

custom_notification.xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="apps"
    android:onClick="notification_apps"
    android:id="@+id/notification_apps"/>
```

Notification.java:

```
public class Notification {

private static Context context;

public static void setContext(Context _context) {
    Notification.context = _context;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static void runNotification(){
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    //contentView.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.notification_apps, new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class));

    // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_apps, pendingIntent);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home);
    mBuilder.setContent(contentView);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);


    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

HomeActivity.java:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity{
    //....
    public void notification_apps(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AppsListActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В custom_notification.xml убрал:

```
android:onClick="notification_apps"
```

И в HomeActivity убрал обработку нажатия, и все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Описывайте проблему в сопровождении с кодом. Иначе люди будут вас минусовать, при этом вы не получите ответ на ваш вопрос.

Скорее всего вы ставите данное `View` с помощью `RemoteViews`.
Чтобы повесить обработчик событий на кнопку из вашего кастомного View вам нужно следующее:

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы полностью правы, код приложил.
я так уже вызываю но при этом возникает ошибка.

android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package ... : Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=... user=UserHandle{0} id=0 tag=null score=0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=..../0x7f04001b vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 kind=[null]))

Comment: Я надеялся, что может кто, другое посоветует.